# I need help - some excel docs not opening in sharepoint

Tags: excel-services

Many excel files in our libraries are no longer able to be opened. They can be downloaded via the drop down menu, but will not open with a click as they should be. The pop-up message we get is;

"Unable to process the request. Wait a few minutes and try performing this operation again."

What is also weird is sometimes they are available for me and not for others and vice versa.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may have ASP.NET Impersonation Enabled, which shouldn't be used with SharePoint.

> Disable the ASP.NET Impersonation at the Server level and "SharePoint
>   Web Services" level.
>
> Via: IIS > Authentication > ASP.NET Impersonation

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2291790

Comment: Thank you Mike, but it is already disabled.